# Ввод информации с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, классы, ввод

Здравствуйте, перед вами очередная студенческая задача. Хотелось бы узнать принцип работы моего кода, который я не могу понять. Итак, моя задача - ввести имя, фамилию и курс студента с клавиатуры. Проблема в том, что при компиляции 1-го студента вводим как надо, далее программа пропускает имя студента, то есть при переходе на нового студента сразу прога просит фамилию, игнорируя имя, а в готовом варианте имя 2-4 студента - "null".

Вот кусок кода:

```
Student Nikitos;

cout << "Name of the second student: ";             // имя 2-го студента
getline(std::cin, name);
Nikitos.set_name(name);

cout << "Last name of the second student: ";        // фамилия 2-го студента
getline(std::cin, last_name);
Nikitos.set_last_name(last_name);

cout << "Course of the second student: ";           // курс 2-го студента
cin >> course;
Nikitos.set_course(course);

Nikitos.set_scholarship(1);

Student Dimas;

cout << "Name of the third student: ";          //имя 3-го студента
getline(std::cin, name);
Dimas.set_name(name);

cout << "Last name of the third student: ";     // фамилия 3-го студента
getline(std::cin, last_name);
Dimas.set_last_name(last_name);

cout << "Course of the second student: ";       // курс 3-го студента
cin >> course;
Dimas.set_course(course);

Dimas.set_scholarship(1);

Student Lyov4ik;

cout << "Name of the third student: ";          //имя 3-го студента
getline(std::cin, name);
Lyov4ik.set_name(name);

cout << "Last name of the third student: ";     // фамилия 3-го студента
getline(std::cin, last_name);
Lyov4ik.set_last_name(last_name);

cout << "Course of the second student: ";       // курс 3-го студента
cin >> course;
Lyov4ik.set_course(course);
Lyov4ik.set_scholarship(2);
```

P.S.: не обращайте внимание, что у меня в коде все начинается со 2-го студента, воспринимайте как с 1-го.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После чтения

```
 cin >> course;
```

сбрасывайте остатки буфера ввода

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы читаете строку  `getline(std::cin, last_name);`
А потом вы читаете только число и после этого опять пытаетесь читать строку:

```
getline(std::cin, name);
```

Обьект ввода читает вторую строку. Но там было число которое уже прочитано, а после этого числа ничего нет, вот и переходит читать следующую строку. Короче говоря бедный std::cin  запутался от вашего кода... (я сам запутался тоже) Просто замените `getline(std::cin, name)`; на `cin >> name;` везде

Comment: Решение не лучшее - если имя с пробелом a la Гассан Абдурахман...

Comment: Для частного случая (для плохого кода) сойдет.  Я просто хотел причину показать , а не решать